# Select element unless it has an ancestor of a given class using just a selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- not originally here -->
<div class="bar">
  <ul>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to select all `li` elements that are *not* descendants of an element with class `foo`. I know I can do it with a fancy [filter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592423/select-div-with-class-unless-it-has-ancestor-of-another-class), but I'm wondering whether I can do it with just a selector. First I tried:

```
$(":not(.foo) li")
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work since the `li` has *other* ancestors without the style (the `ul` in this case). The following seems to work;

```
$(":not(.foo) :not(.foo) li")
```

In other words, select all `li` elements that have no ancestor that either has class `foo` or has an ancestor of its own with class `foo`. Perhaps this is the best/only way to do it with a selector, but I'm not thrilled about the repetition of the `:not` selector. Any better ideas out there?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HsPSv/2/)

Comment: The problem here is that `:not(.foo) li` does not mean "`li` that has no ancestor that has class `foo`". It means "`li` that has an ancestor that does not have class `foo`". The difference seems subtle, but it's actually a very big difference.

Comment: Yeah exactly. And the second one means `li` that has an ancestor that does not have class `foo` AND doesn't have an ancestor of its own with class `foo`. Which I think is the right result, but is a pretty ugly and unsatisfying way to get there.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$("li").not('.foo li')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y7s54/

or

```
$("li:not(.foo li)")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QpCYY/

Select all li's that don't have an ancestor with class foo

Comment: This looks like the best answer to me unless someone has an argument to the contrary.

Comment: I agree; it's better than my ul > li answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try `li:not(.foo > ul > li)`; that selects all lis minus those with a parent .foo two levels up.

Comment: I'm not sure why OP is *not thrilled about the repetition of the `:not` selector*. What you've written is probably fine in JQuery/Sizzle, but according to the CSS3 spec, the `:not` selector can only contain [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn).

Comment: @kojiro: Probably because repeating the `:not` selector in a way that is CSS3-compliant [doesn't actually work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084112/css-negation-pseudo-class-not-for-parent-ancestor-elements/7084147#7084147). The only way to do this using `:not` that doesn't rely on the nature of the markup is by using it in a non-standard way that is provided by jQuery/Sizzle, as given in this answer.

Comment: @BoltClock It works just fine. It's just not what you might expect.

Comment: This isn't flexible enough for me since in the real use case the `foo` class can occur many levels up in the hierarchy. It's a direct parent of `ul` in my example but it doesn't have to be, which is why I want to handle the case where an arbitrary ancestor has the class.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using context along with selector as under,

```
$('li', $('div:not(.foo)'))
```

**[LIve Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/UJgV2/2/)**

```
$('li', $('div:not(.foo)')).each(function(){
    alert($(this).text());
});​
```

Comment: +1 – this avoids the weirdness of using `:not` with a non-simple selector and is likely more efficient than doing the lookup with pure CSS.

Comment: Actually, it's not any more efficient unless you remove the inner quotes from `:not()` - having them there is not necessary, and is invalid CSS so it won't be any faster. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475595/why-do-the-not-and-has-selectors-allow-quoted-arguments

Comment: This also fails if any of `div.foo`'s ancestors is `div:not(.foo)`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$("li:not(.foo > li)")
```

The comments in the docs are quite useful if this doesn't work:

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: That's the right basic idea, but doesn't work, since the lis aren't direct descendants of .foo.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution looks a little nicer, but there's a bit of controversy on the API comments about speed differences.

```
$("li").not(".foo li")
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HsPSv/2/)